# GIMP how to expand a selection?

Tags: gimp, selections

After selecting with the Magic Wand Tool, I wish to expanded the selection by a few pixels (at full resolution) to avoid leaving a white halo around the object due to aliasing.

How can I expand the selection by a few pixels?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access GROW command from the image menubar through Select → Grow.

Comment: Yes and no... The selection you add is "binary", the pixels get either fully selected or not selected at all, so when you us [delete] or `Edit>Clear` the end result is jaggy. Growing the selection is fine, but the background, or at least the part close to the extracted subject (your white halo), should not be removed by `Edit>Clear` but by `Colors>Color to alpha` to transform the pixels with intermediate colors into pixels with partial transparency.